# How can I define an output that can be either one thing or another in Snakemake?

Tags: python, wildcard, snakemake

In a pipeline that I use to work on different projects, I have a rule that takes a file, following the pattern `tei/xxx_xx_xxxxx_xxxxx.xml` as input. Depending on the project 2 possible outputs are possible, **either one** file called `xhtml/xxx_xx_xxxxx_xxxxx.html` **or many** files following the pattern `xhtml/xxx_xx_xxxxx_xxxxx_sec_n` (where n is a counter for the different files).

The problem is that it is not predictable at the beginning if the project is a case 1 or a case 2 project. It is decided in the script that is run as the action of the rule. Thus, I neither know, how to define the input in the default rule which request those file(s) nor how to define the output of the rule that creates those file(s).

I think it is probably a case for using `checkpoint()`, but from the examples I found I was not able to see how.

This is a simplified/reduced version of the scenario:

```py
rule all:
    input: # How to define the input when it is not clear if it is case 1 file or case 2 files

rule xhtml_manuscript:
    input: 
        tei_manuscript = 'tei/xxx_xx_xxxxx_xxxxx.html'
    output: 
        xhtml_manuscript = # How to define the input when it is not clear if it is case 1 file or case 2
    run: 
        shell(f'java -jar {SAXON} -o:xxx_xx_xxxxx_xxxxx.html {{input}} {TRANSFORMDIR}/other/opt_split_html_sections.xsl')
```

Possible output:

`xxx_xx_xxxxx_xxxxx.html`

or

```
xxx_xx_xxxxx_xxxxx_sec_1.html
xxx_xx_xxxxx_xxxxx_sec_2.html
xxx_xx_xxxxx_xxxxx_sec_3.html
xxx_xx_xxxxx_xxxxx_sec_4.html
xxx_xx_xxxxx_xxxxx_sec_5.html
...
```

Comment: You have an XY Problem here. Actually the question should be not how to define a variable output, but how to solve a larger problem that you didn't descrive here. How do you plan to use the result of your script? Are there other rules that depend on the output of this script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just Sultan's answer made more explicit. OP asks in comment:

> the rule still creates the html file(s) but I do not mention them in the output explicitly, in favour of the tmp file

Yes, that's the idea. In fact, I would call the tmp file a "flag" file and I wouldn't mark is temporary. E.g:

```
rule all:
    input:
        'tei/xxx_xx_xxxxx_xxxxx.done',

rule xhtml_manuscript:
    input: 
        tei_manuscript = 'tei/xxx_xx_xxxxx_xxxxx.html'
    output: 
        # Note the touch function
        xhtml_manuscript = touch('tei/xxx_xx_xxxxx_xxxxx.done'),
    run: 
        shell(f'java -jar {SAXON} -o:xxx_xx_xxxxx_xxxxx.html {{input}} {TRANSFORMDIR}/other/opt_split_html_sections.xsl')
```

> it [the flag file] would probably make the xhtml_manuscript succeed

Not really, snakemake will touch the flag file `tei/xxx_xx_xxxxx_xxxxx.done` only if the run or shell directive succeeds. So if the flag file is present you can be sure the underlying rule has exited with 0 exit code. Besides, you don't need to use the touch function and you could explicitly check that some files have been created. You could do:

```
shell: 
    """
    rm -rf <expected output html files>

    java -jar <create html file(s)>

    if this or that html file exists:
        touch {output.xhtml_manuscript}
    else:
        exit 1
    """
```

> Is that not a bit dirty and intransparent

I don't know... I got used to this way of handling such cases and it looks ok to me. Ultimately though, I would say the "dirt" may be more with the structure of the pipeline or the program causing the ambiguous output. I think snakemake is doing the right thing in making such cases somewhat clunky.

Answer (score 2):

This might be counterintuitive, but I would define a third (temporary) file:

```py
rule xhtml_manuscript:
    output: 
        _tmp_file = temp('temp_file_{relevant_wildcards}.tmp'),
```

The idea here is that this temporary file is only used as a glue to link execution of the relevant rules.

Pros: a single rule to capture the two cases (single vs multiple outputs)

Cons: there is no explicit check on the outputs (the temporary file will be created if the rule succeeds, without checking the output).

Comment: I am not completely sure, if I get the idea. Is it, that the rule still creates the html file(s) but I do not mention them in the output explicitly, in favour of the tmp file? Is that not a bit dirty and intransparent? Furthermore, it would probably make the xhtml_manuscript succeed, but I do not see how to solve the definition of the input in the all rule. Or do I misunderstand your approach?